# How do I implement IPv6 zero compression in Powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, ipv6

For example: here is an IP address : fc06:0000:0002:0760:e000:7201:7003:06b7.
But i'd like to replace ":0" or :and more zeros to ":". So it should look like this: fc06::2:760:e000:7201:7003:6b7

The code:

```
if (Test-Path $file){
    foreach ($line in Get-Content $file){
        $line=$line.Replace(":0+",":")
        Write-Output $line 
   }
}
```

I know, that the problem is with :0+. So: how can I say, that one or more from the last character (now: zero)? Because simply :0+ doesn't works.
Thanks!

Comment: Can't do that as it would create an invalid IP address in case of addresses like for instance `fc06:0000:0000:0760:e000:7201:7003:06b7` (-> more than 2 subsequent colons: `fc06:::0760:e000:7201:7003:06b7`) or `fc06:0000:0002:0760:e000:7201:0000:06b7` (-> more than 1 double colon: `fc06::0002:0760:e000:7201::06b7`).

Answer (score 5):

Use the built-in `[System.Net.IPAddress]` class:

```powershell
$ip = [System.Net.IPAddress]"fc06:0000:0002:0760:e000:7201:7003:06b7"
$ip.IPAddressToString
```

or

```powershell
$ip = [System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse("fc06:0000:0002:0760:e000:7201:7003:06b7")
$ip.IPAddressToString
```

I recommend this over using string replacement because it will deal with the issue of multiple groups of zeroes in different parts of the address, preventing you from creating an invalid IPv6 address. It will not collapse the first consecutive zeros into `::` though.

#### Edit

Actually, this method will use `::` if there are more than 1 group of consecutive zeroes, for example:

```powershell
$ip = [System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse("fc06:0000:0000:0760:e000:7201:0000:06b7")
$ip.IPAddressToString
```

Will give you `fc06::760:e000:7201:0:6b7`.

#### Edit 2

Here's a way to get exactly what you want:

```powershell
$ip = [System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse("fc06:0000:0002:0760:e000:7201:7003:06b7")
$ip.IPAddressToString -replace '(?<!(?:^|:)0?:.*?)(?:^|:)0:','::'
```

This lets the class do the heavy lifting, and in case there's a single zero that could be collapsed, it takes care of it.

Output: `fc06::2:760:e000:7201:7003:6b7`

(also tested with other addresses that have different sizes of zero blocks in different positions).

#### Edit 3:

As @Ron Maupin points out, [RFC 5952 section 4.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5952#section-4.2.2) states:

> The symbol "::" MUST NOT be used to shorten just one 16-bit 0 field.
> For example, the representation 2001:db8:0:1:1:1:1:1 is correct, but
> 2001:db8::1:1:1:1:1 is not correct.

Given this, I **strongly** recommend that you don't use the code in Edit 2, or otherwise attempt to collapse a single 16 bit field.

Instead, use the built-in class's zero compression which appears to already be RFC compliant.

Comment: That gives you `fc06:0:2:760:e000:7201:7003:6b7`, not what the OP asked for `fc06::2:760:e000:7201:7003:6b7` which is a pity as I wanted to give you the up vote for saying what they should be doing rather than manipulating a string.

Comment: @Duncan The string replacement approach would result in an invalid address if there is more than one all-zero group in the address.

Comment: @Duncan, my latest edit addresses the OP better, while still ensuring a valid IP.

Comment: @briantist - According to RFC 5952, A Recommendation for IPv6 Address Text Representation, "The symbol "::" MUST NOT be used to shorten just one 16-bit 0 field. For example, the representation 2001:db8:0:1:1:1:1:1 is correct, but 2001:db8::1:1:1:1:1 is not correct."

Comment: @RonMaupin, makes sense as to why the class doesn't shorten the single field. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The string .replace() method uses literal string arguments, not regular expressions.

Switch to the -replace operator:

```
$line=$line -Replace ':0+',':'
```

Comment: That appears to be non-sequitur. How does -replace "." demonstrate that the string .replace() method does not use a regex argument?